# Get properties from previously resolved promise?

Tags: javascript

I have an async function that returns an object after running `fetch` and `.json()`. I want to have more than one callback that take the object as input. Since I need to chain `.then()` to call the callback, I need to run the fetching function each time.

Is there a way to fetch once, and then have the callbacks do their thing with the output without having to refetch?

```js
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch('api-url');
  return await response.json();
}

function foo(data){
  // do stuff
}

function bar(data){
  // do stuff
}

const doFoo = getData().then(foo) // I don't want to run getData()
const doBar = getData().then(bar) // each time
```

I guess, I can save the output to a cache, but is there a way to do it with promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you want to generate a value once and then use it multiple times: Store it in a variable.

```
const data = getData();
data.then(foo);
data.then(bar);
```

Comment: With synchronous code, I agree. but with asynchronous code, will that not rerun `getData()`?

Comment: @Brother58697 — No. Using the return value from a function does not cause the function to run again.

Answer (score -2):

```js
//to check the state of the promise
undefined === Promise.prototype.state && (Promise.prototype.state = function () {
    const t = {};
    return Promise.race([this, t]).then(v => (v === t) ? 'pending' : 'fulfilled', () => 'rejected');
});

function promiseWrapper(promiseFunction) {
    let getPromise = Promise.reject();
    let getFinalData = async function(force) {
        let args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
        //if force available, api will be called
        if(force) {
            return promiseFunction.apply(this, args);
        }
        
        let state = await this.getPromise.state();
        //if state is rejected, trigger and fetch the data
        'rejected' === state && (this.getPromise = promiseFunction.apply(this, args));
        return this.getPromise;
    }
    //get method first method is force, rest will be treated as arguments
    return {getPromise, get: getFinalData};
}


//instead of creating function pass the function in promiseWrapper
//promiseWrapper helps if somehow it is rejected, we wan recall the function without refreshing the page
var getData = promiseWrapper(async function() {
    const response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3');
    return await response.json();
});

function foo(data) {
    console.log('foo data\n', data)
}

function bar(data) {
    console.log('bar data\n', data)
}

getData.get().then(foo) //It will trigger the api, because it is first time
getData.get(true).then(bar) //data by calling api

//getData.get(false).then(console.log) and getData.get().then(console.log), will act same
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated.